# Format date time stamp

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I get the output of perl gmtime(epoch) like below.

```
Thu Jul 23 07:19:52 2015
```

I want to modify it to a directory name like below using perl. What's the best way ?

```
2015072307
```

Comment: What is the last `07`? The hour?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do that is with [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece), which is in the Perl core*.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Time::Piece;

my $t = gmtime(time);
say $t->strftime('%Y%m%d%H');
```

### Output

```
2015072307
```

---

As a sidenote, I like http://www.strftime.net/ because I can never remember all the formats.

<sub>*You can find out if something is in core by using [the utility `corelist`](http://perldoc.perl.org/corelist.html) like this:  `corelist Time::Piece`– will give `Time::Piece was first released with perl v5.9.5` for me.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work this way.

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
my $dir_name = strftime "%Y%m%d%H", gmtime ($epoch);
```